# Lua - Running a loop while continuing through the code

Tags: loops, lua, coroutine

So to make a long project short, I'm basically trying to have a loop constantly run over and over in the background while the rest of the code also runs.

As an explanation on why I'm doing this, I basically am creating a turn based game and I want one or more stored functions (in this case a simple timer to stop the player from taking too long) to fire every second

I tried co routines but I find them to be highly confusing

Comment: Quite frankly I don't think anyone here is going to be willing to write a multithreader for you. Simply create a new thread and switch between them respectively

Comment: I didn't expect anyone to write anything for me, more so point me in the direction of an existing example

Comment: http://hawwashsoft.proboards.com/thread/210/multithreading

Comment: You should use timer events instead of parallel thread.  Timer events should be available from the game engine you are using.

Comment: Thanks but I know how timer events work, the truth is the main reason I'm doing this the hard way is just so I can learn how

Comment: I just did a quick google search for 'lua multi threading' and found this: https://github.com/LuaLanes/lanes